# Redirect of page using meta tag and PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Here, in PHP code I am facing problem to redirect a page after valid login.

Sample code:

```
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1){      
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=<?php echo "home.php"; ?>'>";
    }
    else{
    ?>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="5;URL=<?php print "index.php"; ?>">
    <?php
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
?>
```

Here I want to redirect the page to home.php.

How can I modify the following line?

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=<?php echo "home.php"; ?>'>
```

Comment: What is your question? If you are asking about an error, what error is it? With what you posted, I would guess that you are getting a problem with echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=<?php echo "home.php"; ?>'>"; and should change it to echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=\"home.php\"'>";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send a location [header](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('Location: /home.php');
die;
```

Ensure that no content has been sent (including white space that may appear before and after `<?php` tags  before calling `header`. Otherwise, it won't work.

For invalid login error, you can simply display the form again with an error message (rather than performing a redirect).

If you insist on using META tags:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=home.php'>";
```

(You don't need the php open/close tags in a string).

Comment: Yes Buddy I got the answer thnx

Answer (score 0):

Read this as to why you should use header() instead of META refresh: [Use standard redirects: don't break the back button!](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback)