# How do I redirect to new domain but permalink link still follow the old domain and using a META Tag?

Tags: php, html, redirect, tags, meta

I need your help to solve my problem.
I have domain https://example.com/
I need to redirect it using META tag (No htaccess) to https://newdomain.com
But all new permalink in new domain need to follow on the previous domain.
like this:
https://example.com/permalink123
it will be https://newdomain.com/permalink123

Any solution for my problem?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect of page using meta tag and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474242/redirect-of-page-using-meta-tag-and-php)

Comment: No, it's different

Comment: How is your question different?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this method.

```
<!-- Redirection -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.com/sample-page123.html"/>
```

or

If you used to PHP, you can try this.

```
<?php
  $oldDomain = "www.exmaple.com/permalink123";
  $hostname = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; // Get domain(host) name
  $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // Get URI
  
  if (!strcmp($oldDomain, $hostname . $uri)) { // If user access old domain
     header("https://www.newdomain.com/permalink123");
  }
?>
```

Comment: That breaks the back button and is SO 1999 - at least give it 3 secs

Comment: I have dynamic permalink like this  https://example.com/permalink123. I need the new domain will use same permalink with the old domain like this automatically https://newdomain.com/permalink123

Comment: @AjiMuzaqi I saw the content and wrote the above before you edited it. Now I understand what you are talking about. Do you want to redirect to a new domain when accessing the old domain?